# Github how to give authorization to my repository to other people

Tags: git, github, repository

Hello i'm completely new in the source control systems and i need some help so my friend and i could work on 1 project that we decided to make.
So i make a repository and clone it in my computer using this:
git clone https://github.com/L...ject_Stanev.git. My friend is making the same thing successful. when he makes new files or changes to mine he is able to add and commit but when he tries to push this is what the console says:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/76Wo8.png (sorry i can't add images)
so how can i give him authorization so he can push in my repository ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your repository within GitHub, navigate to the settings screen from the list menu on the right side of the browser.
From the settings go to the collaborators section using the link on the left side of the screen.
Add your friend to the list of collaborators and they will be able to push to the repo.